# Почему webdav-ресурсы отображаются дважды?

Tags: linux, webdav

Примонтированные по webdav папки в nemo и nautilus отображаются дважды. Монтирование идет при загрузке средствами systemd. Как это исправить?

Debian 11 (testing), обновления все стоят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверь не монтируешь ли ты их дважды

Comment: "средствами systemd" т.е. самописаный юнит это делает? Там есть davfs и ещё можно прямо в /etc/fstab монтировать